# Prevent access to extension-less files from .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want PHP to generate log files which is usually an "error_log" file, without an extension. So how do you block access to such files in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will deny all files. Then allow files containing ".".

```
deny from all
<Files ~ "\.">
   order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Files>
```